# Enforcing indentation of properties with eslint?

Tags: eslint

ESLint has the `dot-location` rule which allows deciding if you prefer

```
object.
property
```

or

```
object
.property
```

when breaking on dots (I prefer the latter).

However, I can't find a rule to ensure the dot has the same indentation as the object. In particular, I would like to enforce this style for promise chains:

```
makePromiseSomehow()
.then(foo => bar(foo))
.catch(err => argh(err))
```

And not

```
makePromiseSomehow().then(foo => bar(foo))
    .catch(err => argh(err))
```

So, `.then` and `.catch` on their own line with the same indentation as the chain starter.

Any pointers for achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MemberExpression option of the indent rule regulates the indentation of multi-line property chains, and it treats promise chains as such, so setting that option to 0 permits and requires 0 indentation of .then and .catch elements relative to the first element of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet available with eslint. But we have a lot of issue open which deals with this scenario. Feel free to send in a PR on the project.